# Installing WSO2 EMM from github

Tags: ubuntu, wso2, wso2-iot

I have a ubuntu server hosted in the cloud and want to install WSO2 EMM product. There is a download link on the website that downloads the product. But I cant download it on my server version because the download link is not direct link (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Downloading+the+Product).

So how can you get the code from the Git repo?

https://github.com/wso2/product-emm

The link above is not the actual product as when you download it from the download link on the website.

Im confused how you should get the product then?

Comment: I know it is 2 step work but you can download the product from the WSO2 website and then put (maybe scp) that to your instance?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is 2 step work but you can download the product from the WSO2 website and then put (maybe scp) that to your instance.

Otherwise you can go to the [release](https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/releases) page and get the direct download link to the product

Comment: But how do you build it then? That is a 5mb file, the produc tis 230mb or somehting?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wso2/product-emm is where the product distribution pack is created. If you check the pom.xml (https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/pom.xml) of this repository under dependencies, you will be able to see all the components that make up the product. All the sources of these components can be found at : https://github.com/wso2/.

Some of the repositories you might need are :

- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt
- https://github.com/wso2/mdm

Answer (score 0):

You can build the EMM 2.0.1 from the source code.Clone following three git repositories accordingly [1][2][3]

```
[1].https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt/tree/release-1.0.5
[2].https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-plugins/tree/release-2.0.4 
[3].https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/tree/release-2.0.1
```